# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '...'

Tags: ros, python, msg-subscriber, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I created a subscriber node to get data from a topic. Topic broadcasts humans on the camera in a list called human_list. I want to read this data with below code. However when I rosrun it I get an error stating this

```
[ERROR] [1522830692.692015]: bad callback: <function callback at 0x7f7c0598aaa0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback cb(msg)
  File "/home/robolab3/catkin_ws/src/hand_raise_detector/scripts/armraiselistener.py", line 8, in callback
    x = human.body_key_points_with_prob.x
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'
```

`rosmsg show openpose_ros_msgs/OpenPoseHumanList` is as follows:

```
msgs/OpenPoseHumanList
  std_msgs/Header header
    uint32 seq
    time stamp
  string frame_id
  std_msgs/Header rgb_image_header
    uint32 seq
    time stamp
    string frame_id 
  int32 num_humans
  openpose_ros_msgs/OpenPoseHuman[] human_list
    int32 num_body_key_points_with_non_zero_prob
    openpose_ros_msgs/PointWithProb[18] body_key_points_with_prob
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 prob
```

My code to subscribe this topic is as follows. I appreciate your help to identify what about my code is wrong.

```
import rospy
from openpose_ros_msgs.msg import OpenPoseHumanList
def callback(msg):
  for human in msg.human_list:
      x = human.body_key_points_with_prob.x
      y = human.body_key_points_with_prob.y
      prob = human.body_key_points_with_prob.prob
      rospy.loginfo('x: {}, y: {}, prob: {}'.format(x, y, prob))
def armraiselistener():
 rospy.init_node('armraiselistener', anonymous=True)
 rospy.Subscriber("/openpose_ros/human_list", OpenPoseHumanList, callback)
 rospy.spin()
if __name__== '__main__':
 armraiselistener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287449/attributeerror:-%27list%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27...%27/) by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> def callback(msg):
> ```

```
  for human in msg.human_list:
      x = human.body_key_points_with_prob.x
      ...
```

This is a Python issue more than a ROS one, but: `human.body_key_points_with_prob` is of type `list`, not of type `openpose_ros_msgs/PointWithProb`. So the list *contains* `openpose_ros_msgs/PointWithProb` instances.

To access those, you'll need to use the `[]` operator to index into the list. Something like:

```
x = human.body_key_points_with_prob[0].x
```

would give you the `.x` attribute of the first entry in the list.

You would obviously first have to make sure that the list actually contains any items.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thank you for your answer.